# How to implement Google Consent Mode via GTM?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a beginner question regarding Google Consent Mode implementation.

I'm installing GCM for the very first time for a client. This client uses Axeptio as CPM.

If I understand correctly, GCM will sent anonymous cookie less data to GA if a user doesn't or hasn't yet given consent. This will allow us to get page views and conversion data.

I read through Axeptio's documents:
https://developers.axeptio.eu/v/francais/cookies/gtag-et-google-consent-mode
https://www.axeptio.eu/post/utiliser-le-google-consent-mode-avec-axeptio

And through articles from Simo Ahava and Google's instructions:
https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/consent-mode-google-tags
https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/consent-settings-google-tag-manager
https://tagmanager.google.com/gallery/#/owners/gtm-templates-simo-ahava/templates/consent-mode
https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/10718549

But I'm still having trouble with the implementation. This is where I'm at so far :

1. I've enabled "Enable consent overview" in the Admin panel in GTM
2. I installed the HTML code given by Axeptio via GTM (triggered at Consent Initilisation)
3. I set all the GA tags to "No additional consent required"

I'm not sure what to do next.

How do I verify that my settings are working? i.e. not give consent and see if my tags are still firing and data is being sent to GA?